# Ansible Digital Ocean APIv2 multidroplet deployment conceptual misunderstanding

Tags: ansible, automation, digital-ocean

I am having some conceptual trouble getting Ansible to work with the Digital Ocean APIv2 to deploy multiple droplets. Normally I would define a list of hosts in the Ansible hosts file and that's how Ansible would iterate through each host to do the config, but since when deploying new hosts, we're communicating with localhost (ie really talking to Digital Oceans API), I can't figure out how to iterate through a whole list of new hosts to deploy. My playbook works great for a single node. Right now, the user is prompted to enter the hostname for the new droplet being created. Ideally though, I want to run the playbook against a list of say 20 hostnames and the playbook creates all 20 of the hosts without user intervention. Can anyone please help.

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "hostname"
      prompt: "Hostname of new droplet?"
      private: no

  vars:
    do_token: PRIVATE_TOKEN_HERE

  tasks:
  - name: Create new droplet
    digital_ocean: >
      state=present
      command=droplet
      name={{ hostname }}
      unique_name=yes
      size_id=512mb
      region_id=nyc3
      image_id=ubuntu-18-04-x64
      ssh_key_ids=PRIVATE_SSH_KEY_HERE
      api_token={{ do_token }}
      wait_timeout=500
    register: hostname

  - name: Add host to Ansible config
    lineinfile:
      dest: "/etc/ansible/hosts"
      insertafter: '^\[DROPLETS\]'
      state: present
      line: "{{ hostname.droplet.name }} ansible_ssh_host={{ hostname.droplet.ip_address }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a list of hosts in a file and using that as inventory is the route to take. You'd simply use `delegate_to: localhost` or `connection: local` for the tasks that call DO's api. For example:

```
tasks:
- name: Create new droplet
  digital_ocean: >
    state=present
    ...
  delegate_to: localhost
- name: Add the user 'johnd' with a specific uid and primary group of 'admin'
  user:
    name: johnd
    comment: John Doe
    uid: 1040
    group: admin
```

If DO api access is not configured on the ansible host then you can use that host in your `delegate_to:`

Edit in response to comment:

Yes, either create a separate inventory file and use `--inventory-file` when running the playbook or create a group `PROVISION` (which is what I use below). Note use of `inventory_hostname`

```
---
- hosts: PROVISION

  vars:
    do_token: PRIVATE_TOKEN_HERE

  tasks:
  # runs on ansible control host
  - name: Create new droplet
    digital_ocean: >
      state=present
      command=droplet
      name={{ inventory_hostname }}
      unique_name=yes
      size_id=512mb
      region_id=nyc3
      image_id=ubuntu-18-04-x64
      ssh_key_ids=PRIVATE_SSH_KEY_HERE
      api_token={{ do_token }}
      wait_timeout=500
    register: hostname
    delegate_to: localhost

  # runs on ansible control host    
  - name: Add host to Ansible config
    lineinfile:
      dest: "/etc/ansible/hosts"
      insertafter: '^\[DROPLETS\]'
      state: present
      line: "{{ hostname.droplet.name }} ansible_ssh_host={{ hostname.droplet.ip_address }}"
    delegate_to: localhost

  # runs on newly created droplet
  - name: Add the user 'johnd' with a specific uid and primary group of 'admin'
    user:
      name: johnd
      comment: John Doe
      uid: 1040
      group: admin
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks for the response, but do you think you could give me an example playbook that either loops through say a [PROVISION] section of the hosts file, or loops through a secondary inventory file with all the hosts needing to be created. I am just not seeing how the two methods mesh together. Thanks!

Comment: @Atomiklan answer updated

Comment: Not sure how this is going to work because when you specify hosts: PROVISION, wont Ansible try to communicate with those hosts initially and then error out? I just tested it and I think my suspicion was correct. fatal: [NEWTEST2]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname newtest2: Temporary failure in name resolution\r\n", "unreachable": true}

Comment: Disregard, turns out it was trying to gather facts. Thank you, works great! Still working out some kinks, but the initial ask has been fulfilled, thanks!